# Finding how many lines are different between two files

Tags: shell, unix, pipe, wc

Write another script that uses a command pipeline to take 2 files as parameters, 
compare their contents and count how many lines are different. You will use 
`wc –l` to count the differing lines.

I have tried everything I can think of to do this. I have tried `cmp`, `comm`, and `diff`. I am not looking for a complete solution, just a push in the right direction. What command would I use for this?

Have tried every combination of tags with these.

```
cmp file1 file2 | wc -l
```

Somehow I need to edit this to work right, not necessarily using the `cmp` command obviously.

Comment: Why doesn't `diff filea fileb | wc -l` do what you need?

Comment: `diff --suppress-common-lines -y file1 file2 | wc -l` ?

Comment: The way it's phrased it sounds like you're trying to get someone to do your homework...

Comment: because that counts the # of lines diff displays, but that is not the amount of lines that differ between the 2 files, because it includes the other lines like the one that says 2, 4c2, 4 and the one that is just ---.

Comment: I'm not asking for the answer, I want to figure it out on my own, just don't know where to look now cuz I've tried all the possibilities I could think of.

Comment: You can investigate in `sort` and `comm`.

Comment: `comm -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | wc -l`

Answer (score 4):

I found that a side-by-side diff, suppressing context lines, is an effective method:

```
diff -y --suppress-common-lines file1 file2 | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want

```
diff -U 0 file1 file2 | grep -c ^@
```

For example
file1 contains

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

file2 contains

```
aaa
ccc
ddd
```

Result:

```
 diff -U 0 file1 file2 | grep -c ^@
 2
```

Comment: It looks to me like this would count the number of differences, even if some of them are multiline, not the lines of difference.